# NativeScript & Angular2 - How to bind an object?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to display data from a REST API. But, the UI is rendered before the data is loaded. So I'm getting a following error:

> **Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

How can I bind an object?

The component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo-detail',
    templateUrl: 'foo.component.html',
    providers: [FooService],
})
export class FooDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    public foo:Foo;

    constructor(private fooService:FooService,
                private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
            .map(params => params['id'])
            .subscribe(fooId => {
                this.fooService
                    .get(+fooId)
                    .subscribe(res => this.foo = res);
            });
    }
}
```

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    get(fooId) {
        return this.http.get('http://api.foo.com/foos/' + fooId)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map(foo => {
                return new Foo(foo.id, foo.name, foo.description);
            });
    }
}
```

The template:

```
<ActionBar [title]="foo.name"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout>
    <Label [text]="foo.description"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend that you avoid subscribing to an observable inside another subscription like you do in your component's ngOnInit method. You can replace the first .subscribe by a .map(fooId => this.fooService.get(fooId)). This way you only have one subscription to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy and it also makes the code look less like a callback hell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngIf` directive or safe navigation operator (`?`) (known also as Elvis operator) to "protect" your template:

`ngIf` directive

```
<div *ngIf="foo">
<ActionBar [title]="foo.name"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout>
    <Label [text]="foo.description"></Label>
</GridLayout>
</div>
```

Elvis operator

```
<ActionBar [title]="foo?.name"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout>
    <Label [text]="foo?.description"></Label>
</GridLayout>
</div>
```

I suggest reading [official Angular 2 page about `ngIf` directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) to understand how it works, as well as [template syntax page about safe nagivation operator (`?`)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).